# mysql query for display top 5 average rates

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello**
Suppose I have this table in mysql:

[image]

and i need to get the top 5 movies rated.
i need to calculate the average rate for each movie for example: movieID 12 = (9.5+9)/2 = 9.25 (Avg), and then display the top 5 rates.

any help?

Comment: `select ... order by movierate desc limit 5`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `movieID`,
    AVG(`movieRate`)
AS `averageRate`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `movieID`
ORDER BY `averageRate` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I believe you need to add "GROUP BY movieID" for this to work.

Comment: Hello
This query gives me one row.

Comment: What did you do to fetch the results? Can you show me your code?

Comment: Hi
i add GROUP BY movieID and know its ok but if i add "LIMIT 5" to my query its display the first 5 rows and not the most rated rows.

Comment: have you added ORDER BY `averageRate` DESC?

Comment: Thanks i added ORDER BY `averageRate` DESC and now its good.
thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please vote my answer as the answer to your question? It helps keeping things tidy.